# How to I fix sound issues on the 3mm jack?

Tags: sound, jack

So I have the latest distribution of Ubuntu, but even on previous versions, when I plug a headset into the 3mm jack, I get no sound, and as much trouble shooting as I try on my own, I am unable to hear anything over the earbuds, but when I use bluetooth, I can hear sound fine. I know the earbuds work, as before I removed Windows 10 from my laptop, it would work there, but not when I switched over to the dual boot of Ubuntu. Any pointers?

Comment: Could the hardware jack have physically broke/been damaged since you got rid of Windows? If it has happened even with old versions, the audio jack could be having hardware issues. You could download the live CD for some other distro (say, Fedora) and test audio with the included web browser (on, say, YouTube or simaler). Can you report if that works?

Comment: What is the " latest distribution of Ubuntu"?

Comment: Latest distribution of Ubuntu that recently came out, I believe I have 22.04.  Also, there's no damage to the jack, as this happened while I still had Windows installed on the laptop.